# How to define the type of a grouping by 2 keys

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, anonymous-types

I have the following property:

```
public List<IGrouping<????, License>> LicensesInfo
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Which I want to assign values from here:

```
var groupedLicenses = licenses.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.Name}).ToList();
```

The error says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: string Id, string Name>, License>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<????, License>>'

I've tried variations of `{string, string}` in order to define that anonymous type, without luck.

I also tried creating an object and used it in the `GroupBy` like this: `.GroupBy(x => new AccountInfo(x.Id, x.Name))` but they do not even get grouped if used like that.

Comment: You need to use a real class i.e. AccountInfo which should work. This might be a stupid question, but are you sure you have duplicate id's? (Any time I see a column call id, I naturally assume that the column is unique)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I am sure there are duplicate IDs. For example, the following code has the same results: 
`var groupedLicenses = licenses.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name }).ToList();`
`var groupedLicenses2 = licenses.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id }).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your AccountInfo class implement IEquatable.

```
public class AccountInfo : IEquatable<AccountInfo>
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

    public bool Equals(AccountInfo other)
    {
        return other != null && Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id, Name);
    }
}
```

or if you are using C# 9.0 you can use record.

```
public record AccountInfo 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

}
```